# Adjacency matrix of graph in c ( getting error )

Tags: c, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct graph{
int v,e,**adj;
};

struct graph* graph_A(){
int u,V,i;
struct graph *g = (struct graph*)malloc(sizeof(struct graph));
if(!g){
 printf("error ! ");
exit(1);
 }

printf("Enter no of nodes and edges ? ");
scanf("%d, %d",&g->v,&g->e);
g->adj = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int) * sizeof(g->v * g->v ));
for(u = 0 ; u <= g->v ; u++)
for(V = 0 ; V <= g->v ; V++ )
g->adj[u][V] = 0;
printf("Enter connections ? ");
for(i = 0 ; i  <= g->e ; i++){
scanf("%d, %d",&u,&V);
g->adj[u][V] = 1;
g->adj[V][u] = 1;
 }
  return (g);
 }
 int main(){
 graph_A();
  }
```

I am trying to figure out whats the problem but unable to resolve by myself . please help !
i've researched for about 2 hours over this topic  unfortunately did't found any 
proper help desk.
i am learning data structure and implementing in c and c++ language.
if you could able to advice me 
that'd be earnestly kind of you .
thanks !

Comment: Tell me something, in `C++`, why do you need malloc?

Comment: `if(g){
cout << " error";
exit(1);
}`: you'll get error if alloc succeeds. And more importantly why do you alloc memory for your class in your class??

Comment: using malloc for non-pod... that can only end well...

Comment: Agree with @Sourav, C++ provides something called "new" keyword using which you can allocate memory easily.

Comment: @kiner_shah more importantly c++ provides containers so you dont have to manage memory *at all*

Comment: Yes @Borgleader, but if he wanna learn how to define and use custom data structures, then he mustn't use containers as it will spoil the fun! ;-)

Comment: @kiner_shah Erm no, manual dynamic allocation is a last resort and never fun to use (because error prone). Also, it should only be used IFF you mastered the basics.

Comment: True indeed @Borgleader. One must use dynamic allocation, only if one knows the consequences of poor handling of the memory and pointers!

Comment: You didn't say what doesn't work and what you actually expect the program to do. Despite the comments, you can use `malloc` if you want, (although it is not really the C++ way) but why on earth are you malloc-ing memory for the class in its constructor?

Comment: from here he allocated the pointer or pointers array but did not allocate each line.

Comment: hello everyone ,
it feels good to acquire information from the people around the world . 
i've implemented the code even in c but its throws me an error .
can you please help me on this issue .

Comment: My advice would be to stick to C++ while you're at it. Memory allocation is much easier due to existing standard containers like `vector`, `list` and `string`. With those alone, and coding almost like C, you can accomplish great things.

Comment: This apparently is C. Don't spam tags, C++ is a **different** language (which you should have gotten from the comments already). There just is no matrix, aka 2D array in your code and nothing which can point to one. A pointer is not an array! If you need a 2D array, **use one**. This will be very easy in C (but not in C++, unless you use the standard container types) using a VLA - search for it, there are plenty of Q&A already.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly fixed your code using vectors. Not the cleaniest way due to non-use of auto loops, bad choices of variables, no boundary check on user input, but at least it works
I have removed the allocations fully, replaced by vectors, much simpler, and the fact is that the code did not change that much.

Note that you don't need a `graph` class. Everything could have been done in the main itself. If you want to create a class, then provide parameters in the constructor instead of interactive input (do that in the main so others can reuse your class for other purposes), and provide methods to compute, get access to data, size, etc... That will come afterwards.

Which were the main concerns:

- malloc of the instance *within* the constructor itself. Using new would have created an infinite recursion. My advice: read some C++ books
- all loops include upper boundary
- the pointer of pointer row was allocated but not the rows themselves.

When I rewrote the code, I had 2 compilation errors, one SEGV because of the last upper bound boundary error on the display part, after that it worked right away. C++ rules (when you know your way around)

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class graph{
int v,e;
vector<vector<int> > adj;
public:
graph();
 };

graph::graph()
{

int u,V,i;
cout << "Enter no of nodes and edges ? ";
cin  >> v ;
cin >> e ;
adj.resize(v);
for(u = 0 ; u < v ; u++)
{
    adj[u].resize(v);
}

for(u = 0 ; u < v ; u++)
for(V = 0 ; V < v ; V++ )
adj[u][V] = 0;
cout << " Enter connections ? ";
for(i = 0 ; i  < e ; i++){
cin >> u ;
cin >> V ;
adj[u][V] = 1;
adj[V][u] = 1;
}
for(u = 0 ; u < v ; u++)
{
for(V = 0 ; V < v ; V++ )
{
cout << adj[u][V] << " ";
}
cout << endl;
}
}


int main(){

graph a;
return 0;
}
```

test:

```
Enter no of nodes and edges ? 10 3
 Enter connections ? 3 4
2 3
4 5
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```